# How to create method in controller that applies to all other methods in the controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code in my `adminController`:

```
public function index() {

    if (!(Auth::check())) {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }       

    $tags = DB::table('Tags')->get();
    /* convert Object to array */
    $tagsArray = array();
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $tagsArray[$tag->tag] = $tag->tag; 
    }
    $tagsArray = json_decode(json_encode($tagsArray) , TRUE);
    return view('admin.index')->with('tags' , $tagsArray);
}
```

I have the following two steps to check if the user has logged in , if hes not then he will be asked to login:

```
if (!(Auth::check())) {
            return Redirect::to('login');
}
```

Actually i would like to make these two steps into a method and then apply that method to all the other methods in the `adminController` , How do i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap what you want in a method

```
public function authCheck() {
    if (!(Auth::check())) {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

then from other methods call it like

```
public function someOtherMethod() {
    $this->authCheck();
    // your code....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really use `auth` or custom middleware for that:

```
Route::resource('admin', 'adminController)->middleware('auth');
```

Or use [middleware group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#middleware-groups):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('admin', 'adminController);
});
```

Or define [middleware in a constructor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#controller-middleware):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: thanks , i wanted something like what gayan has posted though , thanks for the nice explanation :) . + 1